# Does gnome have a application move option like xfce?

Tags: window

I've switched from xfce (Ubuntu Studio) to gnome (Ubuntu 20.04). In xfce I could right select an open application icon in the panel and select Move. I could then drag the app window between monitors.

Is gnome capable of this?

Comment: Between monitors you just drag the application by left clicking and holding down the button while dragging from the title bar of the app.

Comment: When the monitor, that has the app open, is in another room that doesn't do me much good.

Comment: Please make sure to add information like that to your question.  As I can see, there isn't anyway to have a move option added to the drop down menus of the apps.  You can look at https://extensions.gnome.org/ and see if you can find something similar.

Comment: I just wanted to ask and make sure I wasn't missing something simple under a buried gnome setting. Thanks for checking.